# Yii::t() complex translation

Tags: php, yii, localization, translation

I have some text to translate with this Yii::t() method.
For example text is 'wordA wordB wordC'.

I can write

`Yii::t('file_with_translations','AAA BBB CCC')`

and in my file_with_translations I can store this

```
return array(
'AAA BBB CCC'=>'translation_of_AAA BBB CCC',
);
```

But what I want to do is to write

`Yii::t('file_with_translations','AAA {BBB} CCC')`
And then I want to have in my translation file the following

```
return array(
'BBB'=>'translation of BBB'
'AAA {VAR} CCC'=>'translation_of_AAA CCC {VAR}',
);
```

As you can see using this type of approach I will have possibility to move words in text while translating. But Yii probably cannot guess what VAR is and is not working in this way. any solution of transfering BBB to translation file under VAR ? So translation file will take this VAR and searchs itself to find if STRING stored in VAR exists for translation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like:

```
Yii::t('file_with_translations', 'AAA {BBB} CCC', array('{BBB}'=>Yii::t('file_with_translations','BBB')))
```

You can read more here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n check the parameters section.

Comment: Ok but in my translation file I want to write {Anything} instead {BBB} and it is not working.

Comment: From the docs, `Yii::t('app', 'Path alias "{alias}" is redefined.',   array('{alias}'=>$alias))`  

{alias} is just a placeholder, you can write anything in there, just make sure you use the same in your translation file.

Comment: It worked! I finally guessed everything , couldn't understand from the first moment. Thanks!

Comment: Mihai , now I went even deeper and made another question, which continues this one. Can you check it ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111023/yiit-complex-translation-with-addition-of-differenet-results-iva-aprameter