# Yii::t() complex translation with addition of differenet results iva aprameter

Tags: php, yii, localization, translation

From my first question I've got the following code

```
Yii::t('transFile', 'AAA {BBB} CCC', array('{BBB}'=>Yii::t('transFile','BBB')))
```

Now in my transFile I have

```
return array(
'BBB'=>'translation of BBB'
'AAA {VAR} CCC'=>'translation_of_AAA CCC {VAR}',
);
```

This code is working good.

But I want the translation of BBB to exist in 2 types: `BBBx` and `BBBy`
So the translation file will hold something like

```
'BBB'=>'translation of BBBx,translation of BBBy,'
```

So how to write the code in way so the translation file will take one or another variant of BBB translation and put it in text ?

Comment: you can use sub-array instead of "," separated text.

Comment: Can you write the peace of code both for View File and Translation File ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the answer is still in the link I sent you to :). Meaning this one
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n
You can have parameters sent that take 1 translation or another. For example

```
Yii::t('app', 'n==1#one book|n>1#many books', 1);
```

You can always create a condition like

```
Yii::t('app', 'n==1#translation of BBBx|n>1#translation of BBBy', 1);
```

to get "translation of BBBx" and

```
Yii::t('app', 'n==1#translation of BBBx|n>1#translation of BBBy', 2);
```

To get "translation of BBBy"

Comment: Try this link then :) http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/302/how-to-obtain-a-grammatically-correct-translation-of-the-model-name-in-giix-generated-view-files/ basically in the translation file you should have `'translation_of_BBB'=>'1#translation of BBBx|2#translation of BBBy',` and now you can access it with Yii::t('app', 'translation_of_BBB', 1 or 2);